# How to replace of a specific line number

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace line number 11 in a txt file using PowerShell.

Firstly I tried replacing a specific word, but it changed too much:

```
$output= (Resolve-DnsName -name name1).IPAddress 

(Get-Content "C:\test\test.txt") -replace "IPADDRESS=","IPADDRESS=$output"  | Set-Content C:\test\test.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it change(s) to(o) much"?

Comment: It changes all lines witch word IPADDRESS=   for exemple  : line 5 serverIPADDRESS=0.0.0.0
line 8 computerIPADDRESS=
line11 IPADDRESS=

Comment: OK. In that case, Martin Brandl's answer below is the simplest way to accomplish your aim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to replace something within a certain line, you can use the index operator on the string *array* that the `Get-Content` cmdlet returns:

```
$content = Get-Content "C:\test\test.txt"
$content[10] = -replace "IPADDRESS=","IPADDRESS=$output" 
$content | Set-Content C:\test\test.txt
```

Comment: How can we do it as a one-liner that can be used in a Nmake file? Nmake needs simple commands, like `mv a.txt b.txt`.

Comment: You can just concat the lines with a semicolon ;-)

Comment: $content[10] = -replace "IPADDRESS=","IPADDRESS=$output"  doesn't appear to work anymore
-replace : The term '-replace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name.

Comment: See @takeoff127 answer below if the above comment applies to you.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone finding that the above answer doesn't work for them, this works:

```
$content = Get-Content "C:\test\test.txt"
$contentUpdate = $content[10] -replace "IPADDRESS=","IPADDRESS=$output" 
Set-Content C:\test\test.txt $contentUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = Get-Content "$file"
$content[$line - 1] = ($content[$line - 1] -replace "IPADDRESS=","IPADDRESS=$output")
Set-Content "$file" $content
```

This one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell 7+
`$output="127.0.0.1"`

`$content = Get-Content "C:\test\test.txt"`

`$content[10] =$content[10] -replace "IPADDRESS=","IPADDRESS=$output"`

`$content| Out-File "C:\test\test.txt"`