# Powershell: Replace text on specific line in file

Tags: powershell, replace

I have some text files looking something like this:

---

Text 05-09-18
Text 17-09-18
Text 17-09-18

Text 24-09-18
Text 17-10-18

---

On line 15 in the .txt files, I'm trying to change from 24-09-18 to 24-09-2018.
Changing only this and not the other ones.

- The [15] overrides the .txt file with a empty one.
- If [15] is not present then it changes all dates in the .txt file.

Here's what I'm been doing so far:

```
$infolder = Get-ChildItem C:\folder\*.txt -rec
foreach ($file in $infolder)
{
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
Foreach-Object { $_[15] -replace '-18','-2018'} |
Set-Content $file}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace of a specific line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519871/how-to-replace-of-a-specific-line-number)

Answer (score 6):

`Get-Content` reads the contents of the file into an array, if used as the right side of an assignment statement. You can therefore do the following:

```
 $filecontent = Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\file.txt
 $filecontent[15] = $filecontent[15] -replace '-18','-2018'
 $Set-Content -Path C:\path\to\file.txt -Value $filecontent
```

You can find more detailed documentation on Microsoft's pages for [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6), [-replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6), and [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6).

*Note: PowerShell arrays are zero origin. If you want to alter the sixteenth line, use the code above. If you want to alter the fifteenth line, use `$filecontent[14]` instead of `$filecontent[15]`.*

Comment: Thanks Jeff    
But this only works on a specific file right?
Can it be modified to do the same to all files in a folder, named text1.txt, text2.txt etc...

Comment: You can wrap the code above in a `ForEach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path ...)) {...}`, and replace the explicit path in the code above with `$file`.

Answer (score 1):

did some enhancement to "Morten S." answer

here you can replace all the line by putting the array index in first parameter of the `-replace`
like this

```
$filecontent = Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\file.txt
$filecontent[15] = $filecontent[15] -replace $filecontent[15],'some text'
Set-Content -Path C:\path\to\file.txt -Value $filecontent
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help This works for me, it looks after files in C:\folder\
In each file, on line 14 it replaces -18 with -2018.
Saves all changes in the original file.

```
ForEach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Folder\))
{
$filecontent = Get-Content -path $file 
$filecontent[14] = $filecontent[14] -replace '-18','-2018' 
Set-Content $file.PSpath -Value $filecontent 
}
```